# MinEvictableIdleTimeMillis setting not working as expected

Tags: java, object-pooling, apache-commons-pool

I have this pool of objects (using org.apache.commons.pool2), from which I borrow (or create) one.

The maximum idle size I have set is 3 ( with a max size of 5). This was set with the understanding that if there are idle objects more than 3, those would be destroyed (BasePooledObjectFactory#destroyObject)

What this does in my system is that it creates and destroys several objects, which is expensive. I would only want it to be destroyed when idle for a longer period (say 1 minute).

I tried setting setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis (the default is 30 minutes I could see) to do this. The default, as well as the setting doesn't seem to work - as in I can see that the object is being destroyed quite often as the idle count goes above 4.

Why could this be happening and how can I make sure the idle objects are not destroyed this often?

Comment: Not verified, so just as a comment: I think what you want is minIdle = 3, maxIdle = maxTotal = 5. => Keep at least 3 idle objects indefinitely, up to 5 if idle for less than minEvictableIdleTime.

Answer (score 0):

using `minEvictableIdleTimeMillis` only is not enough

you must also specify **`timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis`** which is -1 by default.

pool objects are being evicted by a validation/cleaner thread, so `timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis` will make this thread run, so it will check the `minEvictableIdleTimeMillis` of the ideal threads and will evict them.